# Logic Puzzles with Modern Optimization Algorithms

Tags: r, algorithm, optimization, integer

I have the following "logic puzzle" (I think this is considered as a "scheduling problem"):

[image]

In this problem, there are 5 basketball players - provided some clues about their nicknames and heights, you are required to find the correct combinations of players-nicknames-heights.

In a previous post ([Solving Logic Puzzles Using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527987/solving-logic-puzzles-using-r)), I learned how to solve this problem with "brute force" using the R programming language:

```
library(dplyr)

dt <- purrr::cross_df(list(
  name = list(c("Bill", "Ernie", "Oscar", "Sammy", "Tony")),
  nickname = combinat::permn(c("Slats", "Stretch", "Tiny", "Tower", "Tree")), 
  height = combinat::permn(c(6.6, 6.5, 6.3, 6.1, 6))
))

dt %>%  
  group_by(id = (seq_len(n()) - 1L) %/% 5L) %>% 
  filter(
    height[name == "Oscar"] > height[nickname == "Tree"], 
    height[nickname == "Tree"] > height[name == "Tony"], 
    height[name == "Bill"] > height[name == "Sammy"], 
    height[name == "Bill"] < height[nickname == "Slats"], 
    nickname[name == "Tony"] != "Tiny",
    height[nickname == "Stretch"] > height[name == "Oscar"], 
    height[nickname == "Stretch"] < 6.6
  )

#output
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   id [1]
  name  nickname height    id
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <int>
1 Bill  Stretch     6.5 14398
2 Ernie Slats       6.6 14398
3 Oscar Tiny        6.3 14398
4 Sammy Tree        6.1 14398
5 Tony  Tower       6   14398
```

However, I don't think that the above approach scales well when there are thousands of basketball players. I am interested in knowing if some of the more modern optimization algorithms (e.g. particle swarm optimization, simulated annealing, nelder-meade, genetic algorithm, etc.) can be used to solve this problem.

For example, in this problem, perhaps the "fraction of the optimization constraints satisfied" by each combination of player-height-nickname can be used as a metric?

If (not factually correct, just sketching a quick example)

- Combinations 1 : Bill = Slats, Ernie = Stretch, Oscar = Tiny, Sammy = Tiny and Tony = Tree. Bill is 6'6, Ernie is 6'5, Oscar is 6'3, Sammy is 6'1 and Tony is 6'. satisfies 3/4th's of the optimization constraints
- Combinations 53 : Bill = Stretch, Ernie = Slats, Oscar = Tiny, Sammy = Tiny and Tony = Tree. Bill is 6'6, Ernie is 6'5, Oscar is 6'3, Sammy is 6 and Tony is 6'1. satisfies only 2/4th's of the optimization constraints

Perhaps we might be able to say that Combination 1 had a higher "performance metric" than Combination 53, and as a result, it might be more advantageous to consider combinations that are "closer" to Combination 1 compared to Combination 53.

In the past, I have used different optimization algorithms in R for "polynomial root finding" - however, I am not sure how the optimization function, target metric and constraints can be coded for this basketball example. I did some research and found some different optimization libraries in R that might be able to deal with this problem:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rminizinc/index.html
- https://www.r-orms.org/
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html

But I am not sure how to use these references for soling the basketball problem.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: look at integer programming in the lpsolve package.  In essence, pick nickname (independent) from name and height  then add in the constraints.  Look at Z3 Solver.

Comment: Folks at https://or.stackexchange.com/ might be able to give you a broader perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a random greedy algorithm that allows for multiple vectorized search threads. I can't say how it would perform with thousands of players, but with 5 it outperforms the brute force approach in the post. A tabu search approach may improve performance with a larger problem.

```
players <- c("Bill", "Ernie", "Oscar", "Sammy", "Tony")
nicknames <- c("Slats", "Stretch", "Tiny", "Tower", "Tree")
heights <- c(6, 6.1, 6.3, 6.5, 6.6)

getScore <- function(m) {
  return(
    (m[3,] > m[10,]) +
      (m[10,] > m[5,]) +
      (m[1,] > m[4,]) +
      (m[1,] < m[6,]) +
      (m[5,] != m[8,]) +
      (m[7,] > m[3,]) +
      (m[7,] != 5L))
}

fGreedy <- function(players, nicknames, heights, fScore, maxScore = 0L, threads = 1L, maxIter = Inf) {
  nPlayers <- length(players)
  # the first 5 rows of the config matrix are the height orders by player name
  # the second 5 are the rows are the height orders by nickname
  # each column is a different search thread
  config <- replicate(threads, c(sample(nPlayers), sample(nPlayers)))
  currScore <- fScore(config)
  mIdx1 <- matrix(1:threads, nrow = threads, ncol = 2)
  mIdx2 <- matrix(1:threads, nrow = threads, ncol = 2)
  iter <- setNames(1L, "iterations")
  
  while (max(currScore) < maxScore && iter < maxIter) {
    proposal <- config
    blnNicknameSwap <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), threads, replace = TRUE)
    mIdx1[,1] <- sample(5, threads, replace = TRUE)
    mIdx2[,1] <- ((mIdx1[,1] + sample(0:3, threads, replace = TRUE)) %% 5L) + 1L
    mIdx1[blnNicknameSwap, 1] <- mIdx1[blnNicknameSwap, 1] + 5L
    mIdx2[blnNicknameSwap, 1] <- mIdx2[blnNicknameSwap, 1] + 5L
    temp <- proposal[mIdx1]
    proposal[mIdx1] <- proposal[mIdx2]
    proposal[mIdx2] <- temp
    newScore <- fScore(proposal)
    blnReplace <- newScore >= currScore
    config[,blnReplace] <- proposal[,blnReplace]
    currScore[blnReplace] <- newScore[blnReplace]
    iter <- iter + 1L
  }
  
  # print(iter)
  ans <- config[,which.max(currScore)]
  return(data.frame(name = players[order(ans[1:5])], nickname = nicknames[order(ans[6:10])], height = heights))
}


library(dplyr)

dt <- purrr::cross_df(list(
  name = list(c("Bill", "Ernie", "Oscar", "Sammy", "Tony")),
  nickname = combinat::permn(c("Slats", "Stretch", "Tiny", "Tower", "Tree")), 
  height = combinat::permn(c(6.6, 6.5, 6.3, 6.1, 6))
))

fEnum <- function(dt) {
  dt %>%  
    group_by(id = (seq_len(n()) - 1L) %/% 5L) %>% 
    filter(
      height[name == "Oscar"] > height[nickname == "Tree"], 
      height[nickname == "Tree"] > height[name == "Tony"], 
      height[name == "Bill"] > height[name == "Sammy"], 
      height[name == "Bill"] < height[nickname == "Slats"], 
      nickname[name == "Tony"] != "Tiny",
      height[nickname == "Stretch"] > height[name == "Oscar"], 
      height[nickname == "Stretch"] < 6.6
    )
}

fGreedy(players, nicknames, heights, getScore, 7L, 100L)
#>    name nickname height
#> 1  Tony    Tower    6.0
#> 2 Sammy     Tree    6.1
#> 3 Oscar     Tiny    6.3
#> 4  Bill  Stretch    6.5
#> 5 Ernie    Slats    6.6
fEnum(dt)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Groups:   id [1]
#>   name  nickname height    id
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <int>
#> 1 Bill  Stretch     6.5 14398
#> 2 Ernie Slats       6.6 14398
#> 3 Oscar Tiny        6.3 14398
#> 4 Sammy Tree        6.1 14398
#> 5 Tony  Tower       6   14398

microbenchmark::microbenchmark("enum" = fEnum(dt),
                               "1" = fGreedy(players, nicknames, heights, getScore, 7L, 1L),
                               "10" = fGreedy(players, nicknames, heights, getScore, 7L, 10L),
                               "100" = fGreedy(players, nicknames, heights, getScore, 7L, 100L))
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
#>  enum 349753.801 361069.301 377810.821 368307.051 386885.301 490222.700   100
#>     1    772.602   4274.502  14209.154   9021.252  19660.551  79180.201   100
#>    10    508.701   1645.201   2892.640   2398.501   3841.801   9889.700   100
#>   100   1358.001   2225.301   2986.916   2773.552   3237.601   9725.301   100
```